# Is there software which will display a HTML page alongside an editor?

Tags: software-rec, html, text-editors

I remember seeing somewhere an ad for software that would have 2 panes, one of which would display the html that was in the other pane. However, I cannot find such a software now. does anybody know of such a thing?

Comment: You mean like using the inspector built into most web browsers now?

Comment: No, more like the opposite of that.

Comment: If you open your document in the browser you can edit it live as suggested in your accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many, such software are commonly known as [HTML Editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_editor).

- [Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver.html) and [Microsoft Expression Web](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Web_Overview.aspx) are two such software (both are proprietary)
- CoffeeCup HTML Editor
- You can use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/html), it allows you to edit HTML live, its free and its is very popular 
  among web developers.
- You can also use Online tools such as [HTML Tester](http://www.webtutorialplus.com/html-code-tester.aspx), but they have limited functionality. (You can't easily work with Images and other assets on online editors)
- See a detailed [List of HTML Editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_editors).

Answer (score 2):

[Adobe Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/dreamweaver.html) is an industry standard in this area, although expensive.

If you have a large enough screen (or even two screens) you can position your favourite text editor next to your browser and just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> periodically to Refresh the browser window.